# Is there a possibility to call native dialog from Phonegap / Cordova?

Tags: cordova, file-upload, upload, camera, photo

I'm using Phonegap / Cordova media capture plugin to send photo to php server, and this works perfectly.
Nevertheless, I had to create two buttons: upload from photoalbum, take new picture.
As I said this works, but I would like to have a one button which will open native dialog with 
this two options (same as it works in mobile Safari, white - blue styled dialog in iOS7).
Is it possible?

I know there is Phonegap / Cordova plugin to show native dialog, but I see only confirmation dialog and my will require more buttons inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at navigator.notification.prompt?

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-dialogs/blob/master/doc/index.md

The prompt dialog lets you specify the buttons/button labels you want and a callback to deal with the user's input.

Comment: Link shows 404. Probably https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-dialogs/ is the correct link.

Comment: Hmmm, link worked at one time.  I shouldn't have linked in so deep, I guess.  Thank you for the correction.